# Auto completion in Android Studio not showing the new variables added to a class

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete

I reinstalled my version of Android Studio lately and everything looked good. However, I did notice soon that the new fields added to the any class in my project did not appear in the auto completion although the previously added fields were very much shown by the IDE in its autocomplete suggestions.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

P.S: I tried invalidate cache and restart and it did not work. :(

Comment: Have you tried to when closing Android studio removing the .idea folder? Also disabling Power safe mode? from File > Power safe mode?

Comment: Does it show up if you press `Ctrl + space`?

Comment: Can you post both the Gradle codes on your question Please.? Also please confirm if you have installed the latest version of your build tools.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I just realized I had something messed up with build tools. Got it corrected :). Also, I learnt that static fields are not shown on autocompletion of instances of a class.